# Angular 5 FormArray > Cannot find control with path: 'fields -> 0 -> name'

Tags: angular, angular5

So here is the issue I have an object that I am taking from an external API and am trying to bind to a form. The object has the same structure as can be seen in the console.log() print as I am using the same structure for the FormControl value.

**PrtScn of the console.log() of the form.value**
[image]

The first few properties, "ctk", "tag" and "directacess", work fine however the issue comes when we reach "fields" the FormArray where we get the previously mentioned error:

[image]

This occurs to me in every one of the elements of the fields FormArray. It does however iterate trough the correct array length. Bellow is the code of concept-template-edit-component.ts and .html. (snippet only for convenience)

**concept-template-edit.component.html**

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Concept Template Form</h2>
  <form *ngIf="template | async; else loading" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
    <label for="ctk">CTK</label>
    <input id="ctk" formControlName="ctk" disabled="true" />
    <br>

    <label for="tag">Tag</label>
    <input id="tag" formControlName="tag" />
    <br>

    <label for="directaccess">Direct Access</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="directaccess" formControlName="directaccess" />
    <br>


    <div formArrayName="fields">
      <div *ngFor="let field of form.controls.fields.controls; let i = index">
        <div class="form-group" formGroupName="{{i}}">
          <input class="editor-field" [attr.id]="name + i" formControlName="name" />
          <input class="editor-field" [attr.id]="type + i" formControlName="type" />
          <input class="editor-field" [attr.id]="value + i" formControlName="value" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 100%" href="#">
      <i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i>
      Add New Field
    </button>

    <button class="btn btn-primary">
      <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
      Update
    </button>
  </form>

  <ng-template #loading>
    Loading form...
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

**concept-template-edit.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { ComponentrestService } from '../../componentrest.service';
import { ConceptTemplate } from '../../model/template';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, FormControl, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-concept-template-edit',
  templateUrl: './concept-template-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./concept-template-edit.component.css']
})

export class ConceptTemplateEditComponent implements OnInit {
  private form: FormGroup;
  private ctk: Number;
  private sub: any;
  private template: Observable<ConceptTemplate>;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private crs: ComponentrestService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
  }


  private templateCC: {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.ctk = +params['ctk'];
      this.template = this.crs.getConceptTemplate(this.ctk).pipe(
        tap(template => {
          let fieldscontrol = new FormArray([]);
          template.fields.forEach(field => {
            let control = new FormControl({
              name: ['', Validators.required],
              type: ['', Validators.required],
              value: ['', Validators.required]
            })
            control.patchValue(field);
            fieldscontrol.push(control);
          })
          this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
            ctk: ['', Validators.required],
            tag: ['', Validators.required],
            directaccess: ['', Validators.required],
            fields: fieldscontrol,
            trigger: ['', Validators.required]
          })
          this.form.patchValue({
            ctk: template.ctk,
            tag: template.tag,
            directaccess: template.directaccess
          });
          console.log(this.form.value)
        })
      );

    })
  }

  submit() {
    if (this.form.valid) {
      console.log(this.form.value);
    }
  }

}
```

I assume my issue has to do with the .html however I cant be sure it isn't due to the method I utilized to make the FormControl.

**edit:**
 - fixed misspell of type that could cause confusion.

Comment: type instead of tyoe

Comment: @ritaj I must have misspelled while reversing some changes, still not the issue though. But thank you for the spot. (edit: fixed)

Comment: Replace  `let control = new FormControl`  with `let control = this.formBuilder.group`

Comment: @yurzui thank you. I cant believe I missed this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered in the comments it was a simple issue of me attempting to create a FormControl when I should be using this.formBuilder.group.

They both produce a similar looking value object however the simple FormControl object does not have the appropriate methods to resolve the path.

Thank you yurzui.